# Background widths not 100%, stops at horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

Live Demo: http://rafflebananza.com/admin/test.html

Reduce your screen width before you hit the mobile layout but enough so you see the horizontal scroll bar. None of my background images are extending past this point.

[image]

**SOLUTION**

With a width of 100%, you should set a min-width with a pixel value.

Comment: Please don't ask link only questions that will become obsolete when you fix your page. Include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've just added a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: Solved the HTML, Body background images by increasing the min-width, just trying to figure out the top navigation background image one now

Comment: A screenshot can help, but it's optional. What you should include in the question is the relevant **code**. Also it would be great for future readers if you include the code of your partial answer.

Answer (score 0):

as I faced this problem myself,the issue is that there are a content that extends the page even if you background images is not greater that the width, there must be another content that dose,

but a general solution for this issue you can do the following:

```
.body{
      overflow-x:hidden;    
}
```

Comment: I need the overflow to be visible